# ASP.net Identity 2.1 Get all users with roles

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, user-roles

How can I get a list of users including the role name per user?
My app has the default tables of an MVC Project.

I'm able to retrieve all users using Identity 2.1 like this:

Model

```
public class GetVendorViewModel
{
    public IList<ApplicationUser> Vendors { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(ac);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
            var vendor = roleManager.FindByName("Vendor").Users;
            var model = new GetVendorViewModel { Vendors = vendor };
            return View("~/Views/User/Administrator/Vendor/Index.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Right now is returning this:

```
[
   {
      UserId: "4f9ed316-a852-45a9-93a8-a337a37b1c74",
      RoleId: "a17bb59c-285a-43f9-b5ad-65f46f94bb4f"
   }
]
```

This is correct but I need to display the user information such as name, email, username etc.

I would like to return a json object like this:

```
[
  {
    UserId: "4f9ed316-a852-45a9-93a8-a337a37b1c74",
    RoleId: "a17bb59c-285a-43f9-b5ad-65f46f94bb4f"
    RoleName: "Administrator"
    User: {
            name:"Joe Doe",
            email:"jd@mail.com",
            ...
          }
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

RoleName is in the table AspNetRoles.

UserId and RoleId its being query from AspNetUserRoles.

Any clues?

Comment: DavidH, you should provide some of your app code to receive a suitable answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `UserManager` stuff in Identity tends to confuse people. Ultimately, users are still just a `DbSet` on your context, so you can use your context like querying for any other object:

```
var role = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "role");
var usersInRole = db.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id));
```

**EDIT** Forgot that `IdentityUser.Roles` references `IdentityUserRole` instead of `IdentityRole` directly. So you need to get the role first, and then use the role's id to query into your users.

Comment: I'd also recommend extending the UserManager to encapsulate this method.

Comment: Good idea. If this is something you tend to use with any frequency, definitely extend `UserManager`.

Comment: Chist Pratt, thank you. You suggestion worked perfectly. I'm new to ASP.net MVC 5 Its silly to think that I spent almost all day searching for an answer to something so simple. Thank you again.

Comment: Good solution but we're using this to send notification to admins whenever an unapproved comment is posted. Isn't there a better solution in terms of performance? (Without caching of course)