# How to find all users in a role with extended properties value Asp.net Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I am using Identity in a project that has extended properties In ApplicationUser class as OrganisationId.

I am using ApplicationUserManager to read user details.

here is my ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser
    : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin,
        ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("OrganisationId", OrganisationId.ToString()));
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
}
```

And in the AccountController class I inject the ApplicationUserManager object.

Then user manager object gives me a way to find whether a user in  role or not.

```
 var isUserAdmin = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(userId, adminRoleName);
```

But what I need is a way to find all users whom has admin rights in an organisation.

Something like this:

```
_userManager.Users.Where(u=>u.OrganisationId=1 && u.Roles.Contains(adminRole))
```

But this doesnt work as Roles is collection of ApplicationUserRole.

Any idea how I could manage to get all the admin users in an organisation?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894327/asp-net-identity-2-1-get-all-users-with-roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
u.Roles.Any(m => m.RoleId == adminRole.Id)
```

Instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works fine. The only issue is that I have to first query to find the Role Id and cannot just use the role name.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately there's not a way around that.